# Docker Error: Transaction check error in RED HAT

Tags: docker, redhat

Good afternoon I am trying to install Docker on a Red Hat 8 and following the tutorial on the page:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-docker-ce-centos-8-rhel-8/

I find this error that I can't find with its solution, and it doesn't let me move forward

```
[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# dnf -y  install docker-ce --nobest
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:29:57 ago on Mon 16 Dec 2019 03:38:50 PM -04.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: package docker-ce-3:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - package containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.4-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
=================================================================================================================================================
 Package                        Architecture            Version                             Repository                                      Size
=================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 docker-ce                      x86_64                  3:18.09.1-3.el7                     docker-ce-stable                                19 M
Installing dependencies:
 containerd.io                  x86_64                  1.2.0-3.el7                         docker-ce-stable                                22 M
 docker-ce-cli                  x86_64                  1:19.03.5-3.el7                     docker-ce-stable                                39 M
 libcgroup                      x86_64                  0.41-19.el8                         rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                   70 k
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 docker-ce                      x86_64                  3:19.03.5-3.el7                     docker-ce-stable                                24 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================================
Install  4 Packages
Skip     1 Package

Total size: 80 M
Installed size: 338 M
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] docker-ce-18.09.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] docker-ce-cli-19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] libcgroup-0.41-19.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.


**Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-attach.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-build.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-commit.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-container-prune.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-container.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-cp.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-create.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-diff.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-events.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-exec.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-export.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-history.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-image-prune.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-image.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-images.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-import.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-info.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-inspect.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-kill.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-load.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-login.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-logout.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-logs.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-pause.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-port.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-ps.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-pull.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-push.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-restart.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-rm.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-rmi.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-run.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-save.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-search.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-start.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-stats.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-stop.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-system-df.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-system-prune.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-system.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-tag.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-top.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-unpause.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-version.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume-create.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume-inspect.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume-ls.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume-prune.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume-rm.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-volume.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-wait.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz from install of docker-ce-cli-1:19.03.5-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package podman-manpages-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch**
```

My problem is in the last lines

How can this conflict be resolved?

I can not decipher which package specifically is that the conflict is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is caused by a conflict with docker-cli and a package named Podman.

As the OP comments, uninstalling this particular package resolves the issue via `sudo yum uninstall podman`

Comment: My problem is the last line where the Error occurs: Transaction Verification Error. 
It doesn't let me execute what follows in the tutorial

Comment: Hmm it looks like its conflicting with a package named: podman-manpages. Is this something that you use?

Comment: Solved: Yum uninstall Podman, since this package was the one that was generating conflict with docker

Comment: Awesome, I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, just remove the manpage from podman, but keep podman itself:

```
sudo yum remove -y podman-manpages
```